# How do I create an Rx observable that gets an immediate value and then samples?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable

I want to use Sample to reduce the frequency of items coming out of my observable, but I want to immediately see the first event go through without being held up for the sample duration. After that I want the Sample to only give me an item on the sample interval.

The code I have for the simple Sample is:

```
var sampler = Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
        .Select(_ => Unit.Default);

var seq = Observable.FromEventPattern<IntEventArgs>(h => _eventSource.Happened += h, h => _eventSource.Happened -= h)
        .Sample(sampler);
```

So I tried to use this to make it produce an item immediately, however that stops the observable working altogether:

```
var seq = Observable.FromEventPattern<IntEventArgs>(h => _eventSource.Happened += h, h => _eventSource.Happened -= h)
        .Sample(Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Concat(sampler));
```

Then I thought maybe the problem is the Unit.Default part of the sampler so I tried getting rid of that but now that gives a compiler error:

```
var sampler = Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

var seq = Observable.FromEventPattern<IntEventArgs>(h => _eventSource.Happened += h, h => _eventSource.Happened -= h)
        .Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Concat(sampler);
```

I've tried googling for things like "c# immediate observable sample" but nothing shows up, I guess I'm using the wrong terminology but not sure what I do need...

Any ideas please?

Comment: Your code at the end of the third `seq` declaration - `.Observable.Return(Unit.Default).Concat(sampler);` - doesn't make sense. Can you please fix?

Comment: indeed, that's why the compiler didn't like it. If I could fix it, then I could answer the question :-/

Comment: It's not the kind of error that is valid c# syntax, but doesn't compile. It's invalid c# syntax - surely you can fix that?

Comment: Ah I didn't see the trailing ;. That's not the problem - it doesn't like .Observable.Return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
var observable = Observable.Merge<IntEventArgs>(h => _eventSource.Happened += h, 
                                                h => _eventSource.Happened -= h)
                           .Publish()
                           .RefCount();

var seq = Observable.Merge<IntEventArgs>(observable.FirstAsync(),
                                         observable.Skip(1).Sample(sampler));
```

The Publish() method makes sure that you register only once to your event.